# Overloaded/templated function for element-wise operations on variable depth nested vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am working with nested vectors of different depths and need to perform a number of element wise operations. As an example, I wrote the following functions for adding vectors up to depth of four. I was wondering if there is a more elegant/compact way of writing this instead of four different functions.

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b){
    auto result = make_vector<T>(a.size());
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<T>());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator+(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b){
    auto result = make_vector<std::vector<T>>(a.size());
    for(auto ita = a.begin(), itb = b.begin(), itr = result.begin(); ita != a.end(); ++ita, ++itb, ++itr) {
        *itr = *ita + *itb;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> operator+(const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>& b){
    auto result = make_vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>(a.size());
    for(auto ita = a.begin(), itb = b.begin(), itr = result.begin(); ita != a.end(); ++ita, ++itb, ++itr) {
        *itr = *ita + *itb;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>> operator+(const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>>& b){
    auto result = make_vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>>(a.size());
    for(auto ita = a.begin(), itb = b.begin(), itr = result.begin(); ita != a.end(); ++ita, ++itb, ++itr) {
        *itr = *ita + *itb;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:** `make_vector` creates nested vectors.

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> make_vector(size_t size) {
    return std::vector<T>(size);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_vector(size_t first, Args... sizes){
    auto inner = make_vector<T>(sizes...);
    return std::vector<decltype(inner)>(first, inner);
}
```

Comment: Will not the first function alone be sufficient?

Comment: @Eugene I tired compiling after commenting out the last three functions. I got this error: `/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_function.h:172:20: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<short int,`

Comment: `std::allocator<short int> > > > > >’ and ‘const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> > > > > >’)`

Comment: @Eugene I think there is a problem that ADL may not find the `opeartor+` defined in the global namespace if it is called from within the `std` namespace (in `std::plus`).

Comment: @DanielLangr Wow. You seem to be right: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5efa38e02ede403d)

Comment: @DanielLangr AFAIK, adding things to namespace `std` is prohibited (with only a few well specified exceptions). So, how this could be fixed else?

Comment: The way to do it is forgo transform and write a manual loop like in the rest of the suggested functions.

Comment: @Scheff Maybe, replacing `std::plus` with its a custom alternative. Such as lambda: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c70c173bb2ec166e.

Comment: @Eugene The problem is not with `std::transform`, but with `std::plus`, which calls `operator+`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yepp! Correct: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946025d24a0d733c) (I'm impressed.) :-)

Comment: @Scheff I don't have time right now, you can write it for me if you want to :). I also guess this is basically a duplicate. But may be worth of a separate question due to "recurrent" application (though I think I've seen even such questions before).

Comment: @DanielLangr this a duplicate  for my comment not OP question.

Comment: @DanielLangr, @Scheff, replacing `std::plus` with lambda did the trick. I never thought the issue can be with `std::plus`! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's `make_vector` and why are you using it

Comment: @JHBonarius Just realized I forgot to include the code for `make_vector`. It creates dynamic vectors. Edited the post to include it now.

Comment: Thanks... on a whole different topic: do you know that having vectors of vectors of vectors becomes very inefficient? Each time you introduce a new level of indirection. This will result in multiple cache misses, etc.

Comment: @JHBonarius I did not consider this. What is a better alternative if I need 4D variables?

Comment: Create a custom `Matrix` class, which uses a 1D array/vector internally and write a custom accessor `T& operator()(int a, int b, ...d) { return arr[a+N*(b+M*(c + O*d))]; }. Or learn to use a mature existing library such as [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)